# Sort IP address column

Tags: hsqldb

I'm having one column named IPAddress in my table. I want to get IPAddress in sorted order.

```
IP Address:
8.123.10.124
192.23.34.45
```

If I use Order by IPAddress, i will get output as

```
192.23.34.45
8.123.10.124
```

Because order by sort it as string.

But I want output as

```
8.123.10.124
192.23.34.45
```

How to write a query for the same. 
Is there any way to split a string in HSQL

Comment: "* Is there any way to split a string in HSQL*" - yes: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_string_binary_functions

Answer (score 1):

You first need to convert the IP Address from string to int. For example, IP address  1.1.1.1  would be 001001001001 you can use following logic

```
    while(ip[j]!='\0')
        {
         if(ip[j]!='.')
           a[i]=a[i]*10+ip[j]-'0';
         else
           i++;
         j++;
        }
```

After that you can multiple a[0],a[1].... by appropriate numbers (1e9,1e6,1e3,1e0) and add .
However, you need to take some precaution such string which stores IP address doesn't have any white space saved with them and use unsigned long long int to store IP address in integer form